# Dedicated meta sites vs. Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, meta, per-site-meta

Each Stack Exchange site has its own, dedicated meta site. I just asked by myself, why not one meta site for all Stack Exchange sites?

I suppose that many questions have cross site duplicates and for specific questions it would be possible to introduce site specific tags. Are there technical constraints or is it more likely design decision?

Comment: umm... there **is**  such a site. You just posted in it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for information, that there is such a site. ;) The question was rather whether didicated sites and SE.meta should run parallel(as it's now) or not.

Answer (score 12):

Each site has its own community, and it's important that each site's community has a space to operate as a community. If there was only one meta site, then every decision about scope, tagging, post standards, etc. would be immediately visible to everyone, implicitly inviting people who know nothing about the site nor have any investment in it to pontificate on issues which will never affect them.

It is useful to have a network meta site for meta-meta discussions, for example how sites get established and grow, and also for the things which affect each site, such as updates to the software (or like recently, to the Terms of Service), and for common problems facing sites, like for example the XY problem.